# Excel VBA Compare one shape to another

Tags: excel, vba, equals, shapes

I have an Excel sheet were a column has shapes (images) of either a checkmark or a blank transparent image.  This is to determine yes or no.  How can I compare one shape to see if it equals another shape in VBA.

Since I would do this all in code, I need to determine if the row/column is yes or no depending on what shape/image is in that cell.

Comment: Why not use `CheckBox` form controls instead of images?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have shapes in column A from A1 thru A10.  Give each a **Name** like b1, b2, b3, or c1,c2,c3  such that all the blank shapes have **Names** starting with the letter b and all checkmarked shapes have **Name** s starting with the letter c.

Then all you have to do is loop down the column test the **Name** of the Shape in that cell.